# What's the Time Complexity of my Primality Test?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, primality-test

I have a basic understanding of how to calculate Time Complexities, but I'm not sure how to calculate it in this case due to the random nature of primes.

A quick explanation --> Essentially, I'm keeping a running count of the remainders so that I know when the next prime is.

My code:

```
import math

n = int(input("Enter the number:\t"))

primeList = []
checkList = []

number = 3
isPrime = True
while number <= math.sqrt(n) and isPrime:

    isChanged = False
    for i, checkNum in enumerate(checkList):
        if checkNum == 1:
            isChanged = True
            checkList[i] = primeList[i]
        else:
            checkList[i] = checkNum - 1

    if not isChanged:

        primeList.append(number)
        checkList.append(number)

        if n % number == 0:
            isPrime = False

    number += 2

if isPrime:
    print("Prime")
else:
    print("Not Prime")
```

Comment: I see no reason, how the answer is influenced by the distribution of prime numbers, the complexity is O(sqrt(n)), and yes, there are better algorithms, especially if you ony want to know, whether the number is prime or not and are not interested at the factors.

Comment: @guidot The inner loop makes it worse, I would say by a factor corresponding to the number of primes less than `sqrt(n)` (which can be estimated by the Prime Number Theorem).

Comment: @guidot Sorry, that's my fault (I posted a previous version of my code). In my current version (which isn't working), I catch every continuous prime in one go, so instead of catching a maximum of one prime per iteration, it catches between 0-5. So 13, 15, 17, 19 would be caught in one iteration, but in the next one, only 23 would, but then 29 and 31 would be caught. So what would the time complexity of that be?

Comment: π(N) ~ N/log(N)

Comment: BTW, I ran your code in a loop and plotted the timing as a function of n in range(1,10^9), it came out linear for some reason.

Comment: You mentioned *the random nature of primes.* What, specifically, are you referring to? I don't recall anything particularly random about prime numbers.

Comment: @VeltzerDoron if the complexity is `O(n/log(n))` it will look like `O(n)` on a smaller scale. `log(n)` grows so slowly that it is hard to find a scale on which the slope of the curve is visibly changing.

Comment: Everyone is answering the complexity in terms of the input `n`.  Note that the way complexity of primality is normally given is in terms of the **size** of `n` (e.g. in bits).  So if you want to compare to anything in the literature, it is exponential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm seems to be `O(n/log(n))`

There are `sqrt(n)` passes through the outer loop. The inner loop is bounded by the number of primes which are less than `sqrt(n)`. By the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) this is asymptotically given by `sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n))`. By the laws of logarithms this is equivalent to `sqrt(n)/(0.5*log(n)) = 2*sqrt(n)/log(n)`. The overall complexity is thus

```
O(sqrt(n)*2*sqrt(n)/log(n)) = O(2*n/log(n)) = O(n/log(n))
```

Needless to say, this isn't a very efficient way to check if `n` is prime. It is asymptotically little better than the `O(n)` naive check for divisibility by all numbers less than `n`.